# Grab table cell text via Jquery traversing methods

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this structure

```
<tr>
   <th>some text0</th>
   <th>some text1</th>
   <th>some text2</th>
   <td class="edit"><button>Edit</button></td>
</tr>
```

When edit button is clicked, I want to take "some text 0, 1 and 2" and put that inside a form.

I tried to use methods from [JQuery Traversing](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_traversing.asp), but was not successful.

A example

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.edit' ,function(){
   var takeit = $(this).parent('tr th:eq(0)').html();
   $('.a_input_for_my_form').val(takeit);;
});
```

Another

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.edit' ,function(){
  var father = $(this).parent('tr th:eq(0)');
  var child  = $(father).child('th').html();
  $('.a_input_for_my_form').val(child);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just I guess what you expected? if not let me know

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.edit' ,function(){
   var takeit = $(this).closest('tr').find('th').eq(0).html();
   $('.a_input_for_my_form').val(takeit);
});
```

[***DEMO***](https://jsfiddle.net/2432Lpey/)

Answer (score 1):

I created two demos, and attached each demo to a different button

One of these demos might help

```js
$('#btn1').click(function(){
  //Grabs all text in all `th`
  var txt = $('table tr th').text();
  $('.myInput').val(txt);
});

$('#btn2').click(function(){
  //Iterates through each `th`, sticks text into array, converts to string
  var txt = [];
  $('table tr th').each(function(){
    txt.push( $(this).text() );
  });
  $('.myInput').val(txt.join(", ") );
});
```

```css
*{position:relative;}
form{margin-top:15px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
   <th>some text0</th>
   <th>some text1</th>
   <th>some text2</th>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td class="edit"><button id="btn1">Edit1</button></td>
   <td class="edit"><button id="btn2">Edit2</button></td>
</tr>

</table>
<form>
  <input class="myInput" type="text" />
</form>
```